# Is there any Java emulator for mac?

Tags: macos, mac, java, jar

I just want to run a `.jar` app on macOS, but I can not find an emulator. Does anyone know one?

Comment: `java -jar foo.jar` should work, actually.

Comment: http://blog.adsdevshop.com/2008/02/26/installing-the-jdk-16-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 14):

Java is a multi-platform language. There are no emulators, just JVMs. Even Macs have a JVM implementation.

In a command prompt, try:

```
java -jar <your jar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an emulator, you can simply use the [Java VM](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) for Mac.